# Informatica repository information

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Im a newbie to informatica and trying to understand in which database informatica stores all the information , like targets, source, transformation, repository?

If its stored in the tables can I query those tables?

Answer (score 2):

what kind of information are you looking for from the repository tables? As Marek has mentioned, it is not encouraged to query the repository database directly as the chances of corruption are more.

Informatica provides reporting services which you can point to PowerCenter repository and run reports on the Metadata.

If you have to query to PowerCenter database, it is recommended to query the REP_ views as they will be more meaningful and might provide the information you are looking for.

-Sadagopan

Comment: How do I can query the REP_ views , Is it in the designer?

Comment: No. You will have to connect to the repository database through a database client. You can get the repository database info from the repository service properties in Admin Console. If you dont have access, you can ask the administrator to provide you the details.

Comment: btw, if you are looking for basic information like sql override etc, you can download the tool 'Metaquery' from my.informatica.com . It is a good tool to query on the repository db.